# Common meta tag description for a particular content type

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I am working with meta tag module in drupal8.I want to add common meta title and description for a particular content type.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Visit `/admin/config/search/metatag`
- Click on "+ Add default meta tags" button
- On the next page, select the content type or entity you want
- Define your defaults there